# How to move column or swap two columns with csvkit?

Tags: csv, csvkit

I'm using [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.1/) to manipulate csv files, but can't find how to do this:

1. move one column before or after another column
2. swap two columns but keep others unchanged

Does someone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation you linked to, `csvcut` can do the job. A disadvantage would be that you have to list all of the columns.

An alternative would be to use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

Comment: There are at least six answered questions about swapping columns in a pandas dataframa on StackOverflow alone. I don't think adding one more will make it more clear.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [csvcut](https://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.1/scripts/csvcut.html)

```
csvcut -c column_c,column_a data.csv > new.csv
```

Or [csvsql](https://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.1/scripts/csvsql.html)

```
csvsql --table=x --query "select column_c,column_a from x" data.csv
```

If you are used to sql queries the second might be easier for you.

Comment: Thanks but what about other fields? Do I need to list them explicitly even if there are many?

Comment: yes you would need to list them explicitly. on csvsql you can use `*` for all rows like in a regular sql query. You might want to check out `awk`